# Regex to replace a string in context but not the context

Tags: regex, linux, bash, replace, sed

I am new to `regex` and want to do the following task:

I have a string say, `JOHN.S` and I would want to replace the period with tab. However, the replacement should only occur if the period is between two letters. Something that I don't want it to happen is to replace period in `John, S.` with a tab. Instead, I will just replace `,` with a tab, which I know how to do.

If I try to replace `/[a-zA-Z]\.[a-zA-Z]/`, then the surrounding letters will be removed but obviously I want to keep them. They should just be used to identify the context.

I have searched for a long time but have not come up a solution. More specifically, I am working with `bash`. So maybe `sed` is what I am going to use.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a matter of catching the surrounding information with `()` and printing them back with `\1`, `\2`, etc:

```
sed -r 's/(\w)\.(\w)/\1\t\2/g' file
```

Using your syntax:

```
sed -r 's/([a-zA-Z])\.([a-zA-Z])/\1\t\2/g' file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat file
John, S.
JOHN.S
blabla

$ sed -r 's/(\w)\.(\w)/\1\t\2/g' file
John, S.
JOHN    S
blabla
```

Comment: This doesn't work on mac... I don't have the `-r` option and after checking the manual I found `-E` should be used for extended regex. However, using `\w` to match does not have any effect. Using `[a-zA-Z]` will leave this line: `JohntS` instead of `John(tab)S`. My `sed` is BSD May 2005 version.

Comment: Well then you can get rid of `-r` and use `\(` and `\)` to catch groups: `sed 's/\([a-zA-Z]\)\.\([a-zA-Z]\)/\1\t\2/g' file`.

Comment: This still prints `JohntS`. If I replace `\t` with `\\t`, it will print `John\tS` literally. Do you know what's happening there?

Comment: Oh, just figured it out. It seems that I need a literal tab (using `Ctrl-V Tab` to enter). Then it is correct.

Comment: Good to read that, I thought \t would make it. If you are done you can mark the answer as accepted.